# How to kill MySqlWorkBench process in Ubuntu?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, kill-process

I have installed Mysql Workbench on My machine (ubuntu 14.04 LTS)

Lately this software is hanging alot. I want to kill the process

I ran the command

> ps aux

but I'm unable to find the Mysql Workbench process. Please suggest me how can I find the MysqlWorkbench process instead of listing all the processes.

And is there any other faster and lighter Mysql query browser for Ubuntu ?

And yes I'm new at Ubuntu

Comment: i copied result of command  > "ps aux" into a file searched for mysql and then killed the process id, but can some one suggest me a better way.

Comment: <pre>
F S   UID   PID  PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  TTY          TIME CMD
0 R  1000 23561 23005  0  80   0 -  3545 -      pts/7    00:00:00 ps
</pre>

Comment: sorry I'm unable to format it properly I want to add a new line after "CMD" in above comment but "<br/>" is not working in comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ps -ef |grep mysql-workbench

please refer 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/579204/how-to-kill-mysqlworkbench-process-in-ubuntu

Answer (score 9):

Try this in your terminal

pkill mysql-workbench

Answer (score 0):

One of the simplest ways is to use "xkill" command. 
Open Terminal -> type xkill -> then click on MysqlWorkbench window. That's it.